# How to exclude specific directory from video picker?

Tags: android

I wish to select a video from User's gallery app, but I'd like to have one of the directories hidden from the video picker.

1. Directory "abc/" is visible in user's default gallery
2. In my app, user will pick a video from gallery
3. When he's picking a video using his gallery, directory "abc/" won't be visible.

What I currently do shows all directories available in the user gallery:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
i.setType("video/*");
startActivityForResult(i, MainController.SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

Is there any option that I could add to the intent to prevent my "abc" directory from being visible at picking time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any option that I could add to the intent to prevent my "abc" directory from being visible at picking time?

Not using `ACTION_PICK`. You are delegating this work to one of many possible apps. There are no documented extras for the `Intent` for "please hide this directory" or "please hide all videos whose names contain the letter 'q'" or anything like that. And, even if there were such an extra, apps implementing `ACTION_PICK` would be free to ignore it.

There are existing [libraries for choosing files](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35); one might meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just before you start the picker intent create an empty file with the name `.nomedia` in the abc directory.

In `onActivityResult()` delete the file again.

Comment: I guess this work-around would work, but if, for some reason, the file `.nomedia` doesn't get removed, then the `abc/` directory will never be visible again.